# How do I properly register a Rust compiler plugin?

Tags: plugins, compiler-construction, loading, rust

I've been pulling my hair out over trying to get a Rust compiler plugin to register properly.

I have a separate crate called `rust_to_glsl` that is in a subdirectory of my main code.

Inside the `rust_to_glsl/src/lib.rs` file I have the following

```
#![feature(plugin_registrar)]
#![feature(rustc_private)]
#![crate_type="dylib"]

extern crate rustc;
extern crate syntax;

#[doc(hidden)]
#[plugin_registrar]
pub fn registrar(registry: &mut rustc::plugin::Registry) {
    println!("Test");
    registry.register_macro("to_glsl", expand);
}
```

Plus I have defined the actual `expand` function.

In `src/main.rs` I'm trying to pull in that plugin/crate.

```
#![feature(plugin)]
#![plugin(rust_to_glsl)]
```

And then I'm trying to use that macro here:

```
fn main() {
    let glsl = to_glsl!(
        const x: uint = 5;

        static texture: &Texture2d = 1;

        fn hello() {
            min(5, 3 * 1 + 5)
        }
    );

    println!("{}", glsl);
}
```

If I compile that, I get this error:

```
Compiling opal v0.1.0 (file:///Users/chris/Code/Rust/gl)
src/main.rs:2:11: 2:23 error: can't find crate for `rust_to_glsl`
src/main.rs:2 #![plugin(rust_to_glsl)]
```

During the build process I notice that `rust_to_glsl` isn't being compiled (with `cargo build`).

If I add in `extern crate rust_to_glsl`, then it compiles `rust_to_glsl`.
But then squarks by saying

```
49:23 error: macro undefined: 'to_glsl!'
src/main.rs:49     let glsl = to_glsl!(
```

I'm not sure if I need to `use` the macro or if all macros are global.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out i need to add this to `rust_to_glsl/Cargo.toml`

```
[lib]
name = "rust_to_glsl"
crate-type = ["dylib"]
```

And then include it not as a `build-dependency` but normal `dependency`